# How to make a WCF Service work with https?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl, https

I am trying to enable https in my WCF service. I've added the SSL certificate to my localhost and I am able to view the WSDL when I use https in the browser. And the WCF service works fine with http without the SSL configuration in the web.config. But as soon as I change it to use https, I get the following error. If anybody can point me to the solution for this issue, it will be helpful as there isn't much reference for this error.

```
at Microsoft.Http.HttpStageProcessingAsyncResult.Complete(HttpStage stage, Exception e)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpStageProcessingAsyncResult.NextRequest(HttpStageProcessingAsyncResult self)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpStageProcessingAsyncResult..ctor(HttpStageProcessingAsyncState state, AsyncCallback callback, Object user)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpRequestMessage request)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpMethod method, Uri uri, RequestHeaders headers, HttpContent content)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpClient.Send(HttpMethod method, Uri uri)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpMethodExtensions.Method(HttpClient client, HttpMethod method, Uri uri)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpMethodExtensions.Method(HttpClient client, HttpMethod method, String uri)
at Microsoft.Http.HttpMethodExtensions.Get(HttpClient client, String uri)
at MobileScreening.Client.CommonTests.LoginPost(HttpClient client, String username, String password) in c:\TFS Projects\MobileScreening\MobileScreening.Client\CommonTests.cs:line 118
```

My client code where I am making the request to the service

```
static string LoginPost(HttpClient client, string username, string password)
    {
        string key = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var user = new UserCredentials
            {
                Email = username,
                Password = password
            };

            Console.WriteLine("User Authentication:");

            HttpContent content = HttpContentExtensions.CreateJsonDataContract(user);

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.Post("AuthenticationService.svc/", content))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsString());
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

                key = response.Headers["MobileScreening"] ?? string.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var stack = ex.StackTrace;
            var innerException = ex.InnerException;
            var message = ex.Message;
        }

        return key;
    }
```

My interface with the operation contract

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    AuthenticationWrapper Authenticate(UserCredentials user);
}
```

My Service to authenticate users:

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public AuthenticationWrapper Authenticate(UserCredentials user)
    {
        string email = user.Email ?? string.Empty;
        string password = user.Password ?? string.Empty;

        var authentication = new Authentication();

        var authenticationWrapper = new AuthenticationWrapper();

        if (!authentication.AuthenticateUser(email, password))
        {
            const string description = "Authentication failed. Username and/or password is incorrect.";

            BLL.Authentication.ThrowAuthorisationFailed(description, email);

            WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;

            authenticationWrapper.Code = (short)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            authenticationWrapper.Status = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized.ToString();
            authenticationWrapper.Message = description;
            return authenticationWrapper;
        }
        else
        {
            const string description = "Authentication: Authenticate User";

            LogHandler.LogMessage(email, description, Common.Event.LoginSuccessful);

            string authorisationKey = authentication.CreateAuthorisationKey(email);

            WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(Common.AuthorisationHeader, authorisationKey);
            ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

            authenticationWrapper.Code = (short)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            authenticationWrapper.Status = HttpStatusCode.OK.ToString();
            authenticationWrapper.Message = description;
            return authenticationWrapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my web.config configuration for the service

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.AuthenticationService">
    <endpoint address="AuthenticationService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.IAuthenticationService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
  <service name="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.ProgrammeService">
    <endpoint address="ProgrammeService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.IProgrammeService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
  <service name="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.ActivityService">
    <endpoint address="ActivityService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.IActivityService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
  <service name="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.UserConfigurationService">
    <endpoint address="UserConfigurationService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="MobileScreening.ServiceApp.IUserConfigurationService" />
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Who signed the certificate? Are you calling the service from which machine?

Comment: It is a self-signed certificate that I created using IIS and I am using in my local machine for testing. I am calling the service from the same machine.

Comment: Did the browser give you any warnings before viewing the WSDL?

Comment: I am not getting anything on FireFox but IE comes up with "The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.". I thought this was because I was using a certificate issued to my machine name. So I created one using SelfSSL.exe to issue it to my localhost and assigned that certificate to the service application. But I am getting the same error message on IE.

Comment: You posted the client stack trace, but not the actual error message returned....

Comment: I thought the inner exception was empty and it is. But the inner exception of the inner excetion says "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: And further digging the inner exception gives "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.". How do I create a valid certificate to test in my local machine?

Comment: I can see that the certificate is installed and is in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities in IE but still it is coming up that it is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new self signed certificate using your machine name instead of the local host. Configure your solution  to use the new certificate and make sure that it is installed in the client machine's under the Trusted Root Certification Authority (in your case, the client is also the server).

Also, you may also try to create the certificate pointing to the machine's fully qualified domain name.